# Check if a ROW with ID exists in SQLite3

Tags: node.js, json, sqlite

I'm trying to check if account exists using sqlite, I tried almost everything and I need help.

**My Code:**

```js
function islinked(discordid, callback) {
    const getdata = `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM capedata WHERE id = ?);`;
    db.all(getdata, [discordid], (err,data)=>{
        if (err) return console.error(err.message);
        callback(data)
    })
}


islinked(440877393616306200, callback => {
    console.log(callback)
})
```

It returns:

```
[ { 'EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM capedata WHERE id = ?)': 1 } ]
```

However I just want to get `1`, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You don't give `EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM capedata WHERE id = ?)` a column name in your `SELECT` statement, so that is why the output property name is `EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM capedata WHERE id = ?)`.

Comment: i dont know im not very good at js

Comment: Try `SELECT 1 as exists FROM capedata WHERE id = ?;` as statement and the check `data.exists === 1`

Comment: **SQLITE_ERROR: near "exists": syntax error**

Comment: Nvm I just fixed it, ty :D!

Comment: yeah sorry I just found out that "exists" is reserved word. It works with `SELECT 1 as e FROM capedata WHERE id = ?;` and `data.e === 1`